# How to get the lastest update of quality cheklist in Google Play Game Services?

Tags: google-play-games

Few minutes ago I know that [Quality checklist](https://developers.google.com/games/services/checklist) of **Google Play Game Services** has been updated last week. Only thing what I need is what things are changed through the latest update on it. Is there any way to pick the point?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no list of revisions or previous doc versions that you can see to check for update notes with regard to [Quality Checklist](https://developers.google.com/games/services/checklist). Unless, you manually save the updates every time and compare.